# partition of a List[Try[String]] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a `List` of `Try`s, and I need to partition by `Failure`s and `Success`es, as follows:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

val list = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1")), Success(30))

val (listTryFailures: List[Try[Int]], listTrySuccesses: List[Try[Int]]) = list.partition(_.isFailure)
listTryFailures: List[Try[Int]] = List(Failure(java.lang.Exception: error1))
listTrySuccesses: List[Try[Int]] = List(Success(10), Success(20), Success(30))

val (listFailures: List[Throwable], listSuccesses: List[Int]) = (listTryFailures.map(_.failed.get), listTrySuccesses.map(_.get))
listFailures: List[Throwable] = List(java.lang.Exception: error1)
listSuccesses: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30)
```

Is there already a function to achieve this?
(instead of calling the ugly `partition(_.isFailure)` + `map(_.failed.get)` + `map(_.get)`)?

ps: Another option is as follows:

```
val listFailures: List[Throwable] = list.collect { case Failure(f) => f }
val listSuccesses: List[String] = list.collect { case Success(entry) => entry }

// or 
val listFailures: List[Throwable] = list.flatMap(_.failed.toOption)
val listSuccesses: List[String] = list.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

but I am asking if a `partitionSuccess` (or similar name) function already exists in a standard library:

```
val (listFailures: List[Throwable], listSuccesses: List[Int]) = list.partitionSuccess
```

Comment: Why will a generic collection `List[T]` have something specific to `Try` ??

Comment: ScalaZ provides many implicit classes from List to augment the functionality. Maybe this functionality is already implemented in ScalaZ, but I cannot find it.

Comment: `scalaz` is not part of standard library and thus is outside the scope of your question. And I do not think that `scalaz` provides or should provide such functionality.

Comment: @Kolmar scalaz ships with instances for all stdlib classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness sake, the scalaz version, all with `import scalaz._, Scalaz._`:

```
scala> val l = List(-\/("foo"), -\/("bar"), \/-(2), \/-(4))
l: List[scalaz.\/[String,Int]] = List(-\/(foo), -\/(bar), \/-(2), \/-(4))

scala> l.separate
res7: (List[String], List[Int]) = (List(foo, bar),List(2, 4))
```

Also works with stdlib `Try`:

```
scala>     val list = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1")), Success(30))
list: List[scalaz.Validation[Exception,Int]] = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(java.lang.Exception: error1), Success(30))

scala> list.separate
res8: (List[Exception], List[Int]) = (List(java.lang.Exception: error1),List(10, 20, 30))
```

Thanks to @dibblego

Comment: In ScalaZ, what is the alternative to `scala.util.Try("10".toInt)`?

Comment: What are the imports/dependencies for the second example? `list.separate` gives me an `error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: scalaz.Leibniz.===[scala.util.Try[Int],G[B,C]]` (I've tried importing `scalaz._, Scalaz._, scalaz.std.try._`)

Comment: Added. `import scalaz._, Scalaz._`

Comment: @DavidPortabella `\/.fromTryCatchNonFatal("10".toInt)` - also available: `Validation.fromTryCatchNonFatal("10".toInt)` - http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Validation.html

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are now provided with a [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap[A1,A2](f:A=%3EEither[A1,A2]):(CC[A1],CC[A2])) method which partitions elements based on a function which returns either `Right` or `Left`.

In our case we can call `partitionMap` with a function that transforms our `Try` into `Either` in order to partition `Success`es as `Right`s and `Failure`s as `Left`s:

```
// val list = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1")))
val (failures, successes) = list.partitionMap(_.toEither)
// failures: List[Throwable] = List(java.lang.Exception: error1)
// successes: List[Int] = List(10, 20)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sarveh points out, there aren't any specific methods that are per `List[Try[T]]`. But it shouldn't be too difficult to write one yourself:

```
implicit class ListOps[T](val l: List[Try[T]]) extends AnyVal {
  def partitionSuccess(): (List[Throwable], List[T]) = {
    l.foldLeft((List.empty[Throwable], List.empty[T])) {
      (x: (List[Throwable], List[T]), y: Try[T]) => {
        y match {
          case Failure(e) => (e +: x._1, x._2)
          case Success(t) => (x._1, t +: x._2)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val list = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1")), Success(30))
  val (failure, success) = list.partitionSuccess()

  failure.foreach(println)
  success.foreach(println)
}
```

Yields:

```
java.lang.Exception: error1
30
20
10
```